# Teradata SQL Assistant 16.20 , Not showing odbc data sources

Tags: datasource, teradata, oracle12c

I am currently using Teradata SQL Assistant 16.20 to connect to different databases. I am able to connect to Teradata database since Teradata SQL Assistant recognizes the 32-bit odbc data source; However, when I added a 64-bit data source for both oracle and Teradata, it does not recognize them at all.

I am ok with using the Teradata 32-bit data source but I want to use the 64-bit oracle. (Not able to add oracle data source under the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator since it is not listed.) How can I approach this? Is 64-bit data source connections supported?

[image]

Comment: Far as I know, SQL Assistant is 32 bit only, I think you'll need the Oracle 32-bit driver.

Comment: Consider using Teradata Studio Express, which is replacing SQL Assistant, and uses JDBC instead. IIRC, SQL Assistant ends with version 16.20.

Comment: @Andrew , Is this relative to Teradata drivers as well?

Comment: @Dip, not for Teradata, it's one file for 32 and 64-bit.